# Php Include security - Using an Array and name prefix

Tags: php, arrays, security, include, prefix

I'm learning php on my own now and I'm developing some simple sites using php include to ease the page creation process.
I've searched this website for ways to make it secure but, as a noob, I'm always afraid of messing up.

```
<?php
    $siteArticles = array('instalacoes','galeria','regiao-e-historia','precos','contactos');
    if( isset($_GET['page']) ){
        if( in_array($_GET['page'], $siteArticles, true) && file_exists('pt/'.'rbs-article-'.$_GET['page'].'.php') ){ 
            include('pt/'.'rbs-article-'.$_GET['page'].'.php'); 
        }
    }else{
        include('pt/rbs-article-home.php');
    }
?>
```

As you can see, it first checks if the page's allowed through the array and then add a prefix to the name file.

My question is, how secure is this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

It is secure. The `in_array()` check is what makes it secure. It is not possible to perform a Local File Inclusion (LFI) attack on this code simply because the requested page must exactly match one of the elements in the whitelist array.

Comment: Just because I'm paranoid, I'd still use `array_search` and get the page name using the index instead of using `$_GET['page']`